# Form Inside Collapsed Div Doesn't Get Submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a collapsed div at the bottom of parent div and, on click on the head, it's expanding to bottom.

```
<div class="container" onclick="userClicked('product-{{ $counter }}')" data-toggle="collapse" href="#product-{{ $counter }}" id="product-{{ $counter }}-2">
     <div class="row collapse" id="product-{{ $counter }}">
         <!-- Some other divs -->
         <div class="row">
            <form role="form" method="POST" id="productsForm-{{ $counter }}" action="">
              <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="productsList">
              <input type="hidden" name="selectedProduct" value="{{ $k }}">

              <button type="submit" id="productsFormSubmit-{{ $counter }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onclick="submitForm({{ $counter }})"></button>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the submit button, it doesn't submits the form.

(I suspect that the 'collapse' is linked to the whole container div, thus it's blocking the click)

---

I tried to submit the form with the jQuery function:

```
function submitForm(i) {

   jQuery('#productsForm-'+i).submit(function() {
       console.log("AAA")
   })
}
```

For `.submit()` on submit button, the doesn't do anything or console.log anything. It doesn't collapse the open div either.

```
// and also this variation

function submitForm(i) {

   jQuery('#productsFormSubmit-'+i).click(function() {
       console.log("AAA")
   })
}
```

For `.click()`, on the first click, it just closes the open bottom div but doesn't console.log anything.

On the second click, it prints the logs "AAA" twice. In fact, the form doesn't get submitted again (I don't see it on network, and the page doesn't change).

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25127/)

Comment: there is error in `.container` div... remove `;"` in the end of its id

Comment: It's a typo when I was writing the question. I forgot `;` when I was extracting the `style=""`. It's not on my original code. Fixed the question now, sorry

Comment: Can you put a fiddle here? I think it is not submitting because your div is hidden when the div is collapsed. but this can be checked in a fiddle.

Comment: Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25126/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you add onclick function in html then you add event Lister to the same button?
You can try this code it is working

```
$('#submitForm-1').on("click",function(event) {
    // to prevent div collapse
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("AAA");
});
$('#productsForm-1').on('submit',function(event) {
    console.log("submitted");
})
```

and html

```
<div class="container col-md-5" data-toggle="collapse" href="#product-1" id="product-1-2" style='background-color: lightblue'>
     CLICK
     <div class="row collapse" id="product-1" style="background-color:red">
         <!-- Some other divs -->
         <div class="row" style="right:100px">
            <form role="form" method="POST" id="productsForm-1" action="">
              <input type="hidden" name="actionType" value="productsList">
              <input type="hidden" name="selectedProduct" value="VAL">

              <button type="submit" id="submitForm-1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></button>
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

and here is a  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5s1as847/)  where console logging.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it stops the collapsing when clicked on the button. However, it still doesn't make the post. Neither on your demo :/ What may be the reason?

Comment: Sorry i thought you need custom submit for the form so i was preventing its default submission, just remove `event.preventDefault();` and it will work.
code edited and form submit now (i add any url in action as it was causing an error to submit in the same js page).
I hope this help :)